# how remind a professor we were supposed to have a conversation through Skype?

Tags: phd, professorship

Recently, I am looking for a PhD position.
I emailed a professor and he said I chose a day for Skye, I did.
Then he said that afternoon is OK with him, and asked me a bout time difference between my country and his country.

then he did not answer me for 3 days and yesterday was the day we were supposed to have Skype.
now, I do'nt now how to remind him

Comment: Professors are just people. You remind them in exactly the same way you'd remind anybody else.

Comment: Send an email reminder a day or two before the scheduled skype conversation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a starting point.  You can adapt this to your own style.

> Dear Prof. X,
>
> I hope all is well with you.  Did I misunderstand when our Skype appointment is?  I thought it was yesterday.  Maybe I should make sure I know what your skype ID is.  Is it profx?  Mine is maryam.
>
> If you have time next week -- days that would work for me are m, n, or p.
>
> I'm attaching my unofficial transcript.
>
> Sincerely,
>
> (name)

Comment: You forgot to add "signed:  The Beast."   I know humor is not that appreciated here, but I could not resist.  As The Beast (Hank McCoy in X-men, was a scientific researcher before turning himself blue and furry) lol.

Comment: @NZKshatriya - Cute. // Take a look at ELU SE.  There is more humor over there.  You might like it.

Comment: I help out around there from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

You could just send him an email about it. It is unlikely that professors would forget about any interview. In any case, you can send him an email about your scheduled interview.

Comment: Not all professors are as well organized and undistracted as the ones you know!

Comment: Certainly, so best to remind them about it.

Comment: It is unlikely that a professor (or any professional person) would forget about an interview. But this question is about a professor forgetting about an informal Skype conversation.